# What does the error message "The source query parameter is not valid" mean?

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

I have an InfoPath form I am publishing to a SharePoint forms library. It is actually a copy of a form that I am trying to modify slightly and deploy in another location.

The form has several views and rules for, among other things, determining what view to display.

I can complete and submit the form. When I try to open it after that, however, I get the following error message:

There has been an error while loading the form.
Click Try Again to attempt to load the form again. If this error persists, contact the support team for the Web site.
Click Close to exit this message.

When I click Show Details:
The source query parameter is not valid.

There is a correlation ID but nothing appears in the ULS logs.

I checked the data connections, but none of them are performing any queries. There are no control events defined for the form. A Google search for this error message yields zero results. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing some mistake in Query Parameters that is used to invoke Browser enabled Infopath forms.

For more refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772417%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! I was missing a character in the form URL encoded in my workflow.